# empty space validation in PHP with a for loop

Tags: php

as you can see, I have a simple registration form, and a PHP script just to validate some fields. The idea here is, that if you have 20+ fields, and you required at-least the user to fill .. **username, lastname and age**, then you would store it in an array like I have done below.

`$needed = array("username", "lastname", "age");` So, as you can see in the code, I do a `for` loop to check if one of them is filled, 
now the code works for the most part. for ex: if you don't fill the three fields it will say

> You must fill username to continue
>
> You must fill lastname to continue
>
> You must fill age to continue

But, if You fill on field and left the other two, or fill two and then leave one, it will just echo `'<p>Required fileds are filled</p>';`

So, the problem here is that, all fields should be filled before the script can go to saying `echo '<p>Required fileds are filled</p>';`

```
<pre>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='username' />
    <input type='text' name='lastname' />
    <input type='text' name='age' />
    <input type='text' name='gender' />
    <input type='text' name='country' />
    <input type='submit' name='reqirester' />
</form>


<?php 

    $needed = array("username", "lastname", "age");

  if($_POST):
    $check = NULL;
for($i=0; $i < count($needed); $i++){

        if($_POST[$needed[$i]] == ''){
          echo '<p>You must fill '.$needed[$i].' to continue<p/>';
        break;  

        }else {
            echo '<p>Required fileds are filled</p>';
        }
    }
 endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
$required = array("username", "lastname", "age");
$missing = array_keys(array_diff_key(array_flip($required), array_filter($_POST)));

if($missing)
  printf('You missed: %s', implode(', ', $missing));
```

or using your output:

```
foreach($missing as $key)
  printf('<p>You must fill %s to continue</p>', $key);

if(!$missing)
  print '<p>Required fileds are filled</p>';
```

Comment: When you click the submit button, it just says "You missed" and nothing is outputted.

Comment: So that means that all fields were filled. I've added a check to skip that message if so

Comment: Now, Almost good. But, when all three are field, it does not echo anything, or should I just add `else` statement to it

Comment: Thanks man. that was genius although you probably edited your ans 10 times :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$needed = array("username", "lastname", "age");
$error = false;
$msg = '';

foreach ($needed as $value) {
    if(empty($_POST[$value]) {
      $msg =. 'please fill in ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST[$value]) .'<br/>';
      $error = true;
    }
}

if($error === true) {
  echo $msg;
} else {
  echo 'Great! finished';
}
```

Comment: @kranzdot: if you get a lot of errors, why not bother telling us _what_ errors?

Comment: well, there is `1` in `if(empty($_POST[$value])` you forgot one `)`, then `2` in `l in ' . htmlsp` `unexpected .` error and I forgot, there was 4 errors, and I just stoped. but thanks anyway